# Running code only if a textbox is edited

Tags: c#

1. Hi team i m using this code in textbox leave event:

   ```
       con.Open();
       SqlCommand cmdl = new SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT itemcode from inventory where itemcode='" + textBox5.Text + "') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0", con);
       cmdl.ExecuteNonQuery();

       var result = (int)cmdl.ExecuteScalar();
       if (result == 1)
       {

           MessageBox.Show("Code exists");
           this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
           textBox5.Clear();
           textBox5.Select();
           con.Close();
       }
       else
       {
           con.Close();
       }
   ```

I want running the code only if my textBox will be edited.

Comment: `Control.TextChanged`-event?

Comment: So what's wrong with it?

Comment: Can't you store the previous value and compare it with the new one before doing the request ?
Be carreful with SQL injection with your code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

You should check the events first. There is a number of events you can attach and wrap your code around it.

You can use the KeyUp event, KeyDown event and TextChanged event.

You can find a list of all events [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_events(v=vs.110).aspx).

Another thing to note is that you're going to be making a lot of Requests to your database. You should consider validating the input to prevent SQL Injection and creating a cache like system if the values been already entered to reduce the amount of queries you're making, unless that's not something you've got to worry about.

Comment: This would work much better as a comment, as it does not directly answer the question

Comment: That's true. My apologies.